# How to change default Python path to 2.6 from 2.7.2 on iMac OSX Lion 10.8.5?

Tags: mac, osx-lion, python

I need to install Scipy, Numpy, Scikit-Learn on  my iMac, which runs on OSX Lion 10.8.5, the default Python is 2.7.2.  I have downloaded Scipy, Numpy, Scikit-learn, but could not install them because my default Python is 2.7.2

I understand 4 versions of Python 2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 are present on my iMac. Wonder how to change my default Python to 2.6 ?

Thanks

Tian

Comment: What did you use to install multiple versions of Python? And what stops you from installing numpy and scipy on 2.7.2?

Comment: I checked my iMac, found there are 4 versions of Python, they may come from OSX Lion. When I tried to install Numpy, got error message, saying that I need to have Python 2.6. That's why I want to set default Python to 2.6

Comment: That's quite strange, OSX is shipped with a single version of Python. Remnants of OS upgrades maybe? And the current stable version of numpy (1.7.1) definitely supports Python 2.7 (I have it installed for 2.7.5 and 3.3.2). This is not an answer to your question, but I would recommend leaving system Python alone altogether, and manage Python versions through [``pyenv``](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).

Comment: possible duplicate of [osx: setting default python for files in terminal?](http://superuser.com/questions/366776/osx-setting-default-python-for-files-in-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Mac, but in Linux (and some other unixes), running such a command as root will set the default python executable to 2.6

```
cd $(dirname $(which python))
ln -sf python2.6 python
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A quick shift between standard `python` versions on OSX

```
$: defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.5
$: python -V

#   [ Output ]
#   Python 2.5.6

$: defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.7
$: python -V

#   [ Output ]
#   Python 2.7.5
```

#### System-wide `python` Preferences

This preferences for `python-apple` are set on User basis. To set the default python version system wide, we write into `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.versioner.python`. You must be `admin` to do so.

```
$: sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.5
```

If we decide to set the default `python` version system-wide, we should be able to define a user-specific `python` default version as well.

#### The environment variable `VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION`

We can use the environment variable `VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION` in addition to our preferences. This environment variable takes precedence over settings in preferences files!

```
$: export VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.5
$: python -V

#   [ Output ]
#   Python 2.5.6
```